# Is there a tool or process to help FOSS authors agree on a license?

Tags: licensing, open-source, legal, github, cookies

The Evercookie project has several contributors and there is no explicit license for the code.  There is currently discussion on the dev mailing list trying to figure out what the licensing options are.

- Is there any tool or process that can be used to find consensus among the various licenses?
- What can be done if some contributors are non-responsive, can't be found, etc?

Comment: I tend to use [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_and_open-source_software_licenses). Probably not exactly what you're looking for though.

Comment: I'm looking more for a "vote" tracking system for contributors

Comment: If there is no explicit license, it must be assumed to be "no distribution allowed". Also, you can only change a license if **all** copyright holders agree to the new license. If one doesn't agree or can't be reached, then you can't change the license or you must take their contributions out of the software.

Comment: it's called an intellectual property lawyer...

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't too many contributors, you could just create a spreadsheet with all their emails and chart in their responses as you get them back.

The benefit of this is that the only thing the contributors have to do is reply to an email with essentially just a "yes" or a "no", which is so simple that there's no reason to put it off.

Another option may be to look into survey websites, I'm sure there's one out there that lets you email unique links to a survey that doesn't require a login and track the responses. You could look into your options there.

If people have different opinions on what license should be used, the best way to get people to agree on a single one is to ask people if they would be okay with the code being licensed under a specified license (and provide reasons for that license over others), as opposed to asking them which license they would like.

As for non-responsive people, there isn't a whole lot you can do outside of trying to get a hold of them. As Bart's comment states, since your project currently has no license, I believe (IANAL) that no one can redistribute it without getting permission from all the copyright holders first. Additionally, you might have an issue with people who are going to be very stubborn about what license they want. The only thing you can do is try to negotiate. I'd like to think that people who contribute to open source software are going to be fairly relaxed about this kind of stuff, but you never know... some people have very strong opinions on software licenses.